# Moving from mysql to mysqli - on windows, with IIS - Guideline

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I must upgrade an old project which uses mysql database and php.

Does exist a guideline to moving from mysql to mysqli?

- I began by checking php.ini: php_mysqli.dll
- I checked IIS: nothing to change
- Convert the calls

Is it too minimalist?

Comment: So it works, you're just worried that you didn't have enough to do?

Comment: When you compose a question, there's a preview panel below the text area where you type. You can use it to verify that the question is readable. (I've done it for you this time.)